# How to get selected items from the rss file?

Tags: c#, xml, rss

Example code:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>Title /title>
    <link>Link</link>
    <description>Desc</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>Link</link>
    <description>Desc</description>   
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I get data from link:

```
XElement rss = XElement.Load("http://examplelink.com/file.rss");
```

and i want to save it but without any other elements, only title and link:

```
rss.Save(@"C:\doc.txt");
```

How to do that?

Comment: Could you post expected output document given above rss as the input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Syndication Feed` class from `System.ServiceModel.Syndication`.

Take a look at this [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steveres/archive/2008/01/20/using-syndicationfeed-to-displaying-photos-from-spaces-live-com.aspx)